# Receiving massive latency on a recursive function(s) for awaiting input

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, discord.js

I have the following code

```
const Discord = require("discord.js"),
  { MessageEmbed } = Discord,
  ms = require("ms"),

module.exports.run = async (client, message) => {
  async function awaitMessages(func) {
    let output;

    const m = await message.channel.awaitMessages({ filter: m => m.author.id === message.author.id, time: 60000 });

    if (m.content !== "cancel") output = await func(m);
    else return await message.channel.send("cancelled") && null;

    if (typeof output === "function")  return await output() && awaitMessages(func);
    else return output;
  }

  function makeWaitArg(argName, description) {
    const embeds = [new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(`Giveaway ${argName}`)
      .setDescription(description + " within the next 60 seconds.")
      .setColor("#2F3136")
      .setTimestamp()
      .setFooter("Create A Giveaway! | Type cancel to cancel.", message.author.displayAvatarURL())];

    return () => message.channel.send({ embeds: embeds })
  };

  function makeError(title, desc) {
    const embeds = [new MessageEmbed().setFooter("type cancel to cancel")];
    return () => message.channel.send({ embed: embeds })
  }
  
  const channel = await awaitMessages(makeWaitArg("Channel", "Please type the channel you want the giveaway to be in."), ({content}) => {
    if (message.guild.channels.cache.has(content) || message.guild.channel.cache.get(content)) return content;
    else return makeError("Channel", "That channel doesn't exist. Try Again.");
  }),
   prize = await awaitMessages(makeWaitArg("Prize.", "Please send what you would like the giveaway prize to be"), ({ content }) => {
    if (content.length > 256) return makeError("Giveaway Prize Too Long.", "Please ensure the giveaway prize is less than 256 characters. Try again.");
    else return content;
  }),
  // ill do those just be quick with logic
  winnerCount = await awaitMessages(makeWaitArg("Winner Count.","Please send how many winners you would like the giveaway to have"), ({ content }) => {
    if (isNaN(content)) return makeError("Invalid Winner Count.", "Please provide valid numbers as the winner count. Try again.");
    else if (parseInt(content) > 15) return makeError("You can not have more than 15 winners per giveaway!")
    else return content; 
  }),
  time = await awaitMessages(makeWaitArg("Time.", "Please send how long you would like the giveaway to last"), ({ content }) => {
    if (!ms(content)) return makeError("Invalid Time.", "Please provide a valid time. Try again.");
    else return ms(content);
  })

  if (!channel || !prize || !winnerCount || !time) return;
  // Start the giveaway

};
```

Recursion is being used to appropriately ask for multiple inputs upon failure to provide a correct input, according to my logic everything should work fine and from what I observe is that I face a massive latency between two of the steps which might be due to unnecessary load on the system while performing recursion, I need to know where that is originating and would like to rectify it.

Comment: Consider using a `do...while` statement instead of recursion, imo it looks cleaner.

Comment: would have to refactor , do you possibly diagnose what could be going wrong? I say it's around line 18.